# AWS coiffure stopped working. CI/CD gitlab.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I'm using GitLab CI tool and was using this script for a few months with no problems at all:

```yaml
    - curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
    - unzip awscli-bundle.zip
    - ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set region us-east-1
...
```

This worked fine before, but yesterday it started to give this error on `aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` line:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
usage: 
Note: AWS CLI version 2, the latest major version of the AWS CLI, is now stable and recommended for general use. For more information, see the AWS CLI version 2 installation instructions at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: value
```

I'm sure I'm using awscli1

Would be very grateful for some help :)

Comment: I seems that `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` is not defined. Can verify it is not empty and has correct value?

Comment: it does, I have even tried to input it there directly. No change

Comment: were you able to fix this?